# UITextField not responds to touch events when added to UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uitextfield

I have an issue with UITextField that do not respond to the touch events when it's added to ContainerView. When I try to add UITextField to the main UIViewController it seems to be fine and it responds (keyboard is showing).

I tried to bring the subview to the front, enabled user interaction on ContainerView - nothing helped.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.containerView = UIView()

    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.containerView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    self.scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    setupGesturesAndMap()
    setupActivityIndicator()
    setupCircleButton()
    setupBrowseTextField()

    // Initializing status
    status = Status.Init
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds
    containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
}
```

and there is function responsible for setup of browseTextField:

```
func setupBrowseTextField() {

    // Setup of browseTextField
    browseTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(10, self.view.frame.height / 2, self.view.frame.width - 20, self.view.frame.height / 12))
    browseTextField.placeholder = "Enter your destination here"
    browseTextField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
    browseTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    browseTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    browseTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    browseTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    browseTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    browseTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    browseTextField.delegate = self

    containerView.addSubview(browseTextField)
}
```

Would anyone of you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think that you have to change the textfield's delegate to the scrollview or the container view. So: `browseTextField.delegate = self.scrollView` **or** `browseTextField.delegate = self.containerView`

Comment: I don't think setting the delegate to the scroll view or the container view will affect anything, to be honest (why would it?). Most likely you have some gesture conflicting with the text field tap. I'd advise you add the `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` method in the gesture delegate and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have set the frame of the containerView as

```
containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
```

scrollView.contentSize.width is 0.

This solves your problem.

```
containerView.frame = self.view.bounds
```

Also your can give the containerView size by the frame size of the scrollView as

```
containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, scrollView.contentSize.width was actually 0.... I would never came up with that ;) thank a lot again.